# Get all image files with wget

Tags: command-line, wget

I am trying to download all the image file in a folder. I tried

```
wget -r  https://example.com/
```

And

```
wget https://example.com/*.jpg
```

These didn't work. Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a target web server has directory indexing enabled, and all the files to download are located in the same directory, you can download all of them, by using wget's recursive retrieval option.

use

```
wget -r -l1 -A.jpg http://www.example.com/test/
```

it will download all `.jpg` file from directory `test`.

if you don't want to download all file then the infos below will be helpful.

```
   -A acclist --accept acclist
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to 
       accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?,
       [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be 
       treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

   --accept-regex urlregex
   --reject-regex urlregex
       Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.
```

like :

```
wget -r --no-parent -A '*.jpg' http://example.com/test/
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
wget -r --level=1 -A.jpg --ignore-length -x -np http://example.com/folder/
```

What does this do?

> `-r` : Recursive retrieving (important)
>   `--level=0` : Specify recursion maximum depth level. 1 for just this directory.
>   `-x` : Force dirs, create an hierarchy of directories even if one would not been created otherwise
>   `-np` : no parent, do not ascend to parent dir when retrieving recursively
>   `-A.type` : only download files with the extension `type`.

[Source](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/128-desktops/18573)

My pronouns are He / Him